# Check if DEP is enabled

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, data-execution-prevention

Is it possible to check if Data Execution Prevention is enabled?

Is there any function that works the same as this CMD command

```
wmic OS Get DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy
```

And returns something like this?

```
0 – DEP is disabled for all processes.
1 – DEP is enabled for all processes.
2 – DEP is enabled for only Windows system components and services. (Default)
3 – DEP is enabled for all processes.
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define, DEP is ON in system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057636/how-to-define-dep-is-on-in-system)

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for not trying to search that. Also this isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GetSystemDEPPolicy function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736298):

> This function returns a value of type DEP_SYSTEM_POLICY_TYPE, which can be one of the following values: AlwaysOff, AlwaysOn, OptIn, OptOut.